# Java Gridlayout: variable column count depending on Panel width

Tags: java, grid-layout, dynamic-columns

I have a Java Application with a Panel inside a Scrollview.
The Panels Layout is a Gridlayout, and it has multiple Checkboxes.

Example:

Checkbox01  Checkbox02  Checkbox03  Checkbox04

Checkbox05  Checkbox06  Checkbox07  Checkbox08

Checkbox09  Checkbox10  Checkbox11  Checkbox12

When i resize the Panel, i want to increase/decrease the Columncount of the Gridlayout depending on the width of the Panel, so that the width of the Checkboxes stays the same. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own Question:
Just use FlowLayout instead of Gridlayout..
It does exactly what i want